# Sequential Loading Using Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, bluebird, es6-promise

I've got an array of asynchronous calls that I want to be called sequentially, meaning that I don't want to call the second promise until the first is complete, and so on.

In the following example, I've got a loop that creates unique images on the fly and appends them to the page. I want the images to be appended in order, but for some reason they don't **always** render in the exact order they are created in:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var promise = Promise.resolve();
for(var i = 0; i<100; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        promise = promise.then(function() {
            createPromise(container, i);
        });
    })(i);
}

function createPromise(container, i) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,  reject) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            container.appendChild(img);
            resolve();
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            reject();
        };
        img.src = "http://placehold.it/100x100?text=Image+" + i + "&v=" + Date.now();
    });
}
```

```css
img { float: left; margin: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/2.9.27/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

I also created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbg4fxkk/1/) that illustrates the problem.

I am using bluebird, but I'd prefer to stick to native ES6 implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am correct, this block is causing the issue:

```
    promise = promise.then(function() {
        createPromise(container, i);
    });
```

`createPromise` returns a promise but, inside `then` you are not returning that promise, so it would assume `return undefined;`(the default for all js functions) and hence none of the subsequent promises would wait for the predecessors to finish before starting. Try changing it to:

```
    promise = promise.then(function() {
        return createPromise(container, i);
    });
```

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var promise = Promise.resolve();
for(var i = 0; i<100; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        promise = promise.then(function() {
            return createPromise(container, i);
        });
    })(i);
}

function createPromise(container, i) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,  reject) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            container.appendChild(img);
            resolve();
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            reject();
        };
        img.src = "http://placehold.it/100x100?text=Image+" + i + "&v=" + Date.now();
    });
}
```

```css
img { float: left; margin: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/2.9.27/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```